# Absolute fastest way of sending a transaction on Ethereuem? (in 2022)

Tags: private-blockchain, raw-transaction, txpool, full-node, frontrunning

What is the absolute fastest way of sending a transaction on Ethereum? (use case: trading microcap coins on Ethereum blockchain which are highly volatile so transaction speed matters)

Would it require running your own Ethereum validator node which requires 32 ETH? Is there anything faster?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do transactions is [miner extractable value service providers](https://docs.flashbots.net/).